# Get a count of elements that appear once in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is it possible to get an integer count of elements that appear only once in a list with LINQ without creating a temporary list of those values and then counting that list?

Obviously this doesn't work but something like:

```
int test = list.Count(s => s.id).Where(s.id.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: What is `s.id`? How do you know that an element appears only once? Do you compare by reference or by `s.id`?

Comment: Use `Distinct` method.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov The `Distinct` wouldn't give me elements that appear once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to group them and the project the items which have count of 1 and then count the number of groups:

```
int test = list.GroupBy(s => s.id).
               .Where(g=> g.Count() == 1)
               .Count();
```

Comment: From my quick testing, seems as if both yours and itsme86 answers work.  Is there any significant difference between yours and his?

Comment: ``Count()`` internally filters items and then count them, while in first one we are filtering and then counting, you can benchmark both for performance concerns

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy()`:

```
int test = list.GroupBy(s => s.id).Count(g => g.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: From my quick testing, seems as if both yours and Ehsan Sajjad answers work.  Is there any significant difference between yours and his?

Comment: Just that mine avoids a `Where()` call by using the predicate in `Count()`.

Comment: ``Count()`` internally filters items and then count them, while in first one we are filtering and then counting, you can benchmark both for performance concerns

Comment: Bench marking would make a difference if there are millions of records to produce substantial difference